# Parser Error The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Path.GetFileName(Eval("MediaFileLink").ToString()) %>'
                NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("http://www.someurlwithparams.com/{0}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Eval("MediaFileLink").ToString()).Substring(0, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Eval("MediaFileLink").ToString()).IndexOf('_'))) %>' Target="_blank" />
```

I get the Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed. I already checked for missing closing tags or double quotes but somehow I miss the error.

Comment: It seems fine, I don't get any parsing error.

Comment: Try `IndexOf("_")` instead of using single quotes.

Comment: @NikhilVartak, that fixed it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexOf method probably causing this issue as it closes you server tag at first `'` symbol. Try to change it to `ToString().IndexOf("_")`